# What is the correct $expression for get all CKEDITOR nodes with DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, api-platform.com

I use ApiPlatform and want to get all nodes (only elements that is considered as node in CKEDITOR 5 ). So what is the correct XPath expression?

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->loadHTML($givenAnswer);
    // Create an XPath object
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

     // Define the XPath expression to select specific elements (node elements for CKeditor using by BO)
     $expression = ?;

     // Query the document using the XPath expression
     $nodes = $xpath->query($expression);
```

I tried

```
`$expression = '//*[self::div[not(self::div/p | self::div/h1 | self::div/h2 | self::div/h3 | self::div/h4 | self::div/h5 | self::div/h6 | self::div/blockquote | self::div/ul | self::div/ol | self::div/li | self::div/pre | self::div/figure | self::div/figcaption | self::div/table | self::div/thead | self::div/tbody | self::div/tr | self::div/td | self::div/th)] or self::p or self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4 or self::h5 or self::h6 or self::blockquote or self::ul or self::ol or self::li or self::pre or self::figure or self::figcaption or self::table or self::thead or self::tbody or self::tr or self::td or self::th][self::p[self::p/img] or (normalize-space() != "" and string-length(normalize-space()) > 0)]';`
```

Not correct because `<p></p>` is considered as node in CKEDITOR and not `<div></div>`.